# this.close() is not recognised as method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to close a window while opening a new one, but this.close() is not recognised by the system

```
private void Insert_Data_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            MainWindow DataWindow = new MainWindow();
            DataWindow.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Here it is the class declaration

```
public partial class Home_autismo : MetroWindow
```

and the included libraries

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;
```

Any idea why this.Close() is not recognised?

Comment: Have you tried `Application.Exit()`?

Comment: Can you elaborate? It doesn't work on runtime or it doesn't even compile? I have the exact same code in my application and this simply works. `Application.Exit()` quits the application which is not handy when trying to switch windows.

Comment: Also make sure your xaml file is not a usercontrol or page but starts with something like `<Controls:MetroWindow`

Answer (score 0):

Try add a closing event that when It's closing it will open your data window
Add in XAML on your window the closing event

```
 <Window x:Class="ParamCreator.PasswordWindow"    
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml
 Closed="Home_autismo_Closing">
```

Then in your main class, do this.Close(); should recognise it then

```
public partial class Home_autismo : MetroWindow
  {

 private void Home_autismo_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow DataWindow = new MainWindow();
        DataWindow.Show();
    }
    // Logic
    If(...)
  {
  this.Close();
   }
  }
```

Comment: Close() should be included in MetroWindow Class. It's not depending on ad hoc events in the xaml code. I'm am probably missing something.

Comment: That's fine... But your not doing close() in your main class, your doing it in a xaml event handler... Look at my edited answer

Comment: yea, but there is no close event whether I'm not able to close the window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down , this is when you should vote down an answer, not just cause it wasn't correct, people won't try and help you then